# Generating PDF on the front-end vs back-end

Tags: html, angular, spring, pdf-generation, jspdf

I have a Angular SPA which has many form fields on UI. On click of Submit, I want to create a PDF(approx 2 pages) file and store it to S3, and then just preview pdf on front-end.

My questions are

- Where I should create the PDF file at frontend or backend?
- if frontend, would it be the html to pdf first? what libs i can use?
- if backend, should i send only payload to backend? no html code required related to pdf on FE? are there any libs for BE?
- how to preview PDF on front-end from storage?

So, total how many services will be required to perform these tasks? If someone can provide high level idea.

I already created Angular form UI. Now next task is to perform create pdf, store pdf and preview pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backend must manage the creation (and updating, deletion...) of the PDF.

The frontend should not handle this kind of work. Backend languages ​​are much more adequate and efficient for handling heavy work such as PDF generation.

So yes you send the payload to the backend, the backend will take care of generating the PDF file and saving it in S3. This is the URL of the PDF on S3 that should be sent to the frontend.

You will be able to display the PDF on the frontend with the following html tags:

```
<iframe src="example/path/to/S3/disk" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Or

```
<embed src="example/path/to/S3/disk" width="100" height="500" type="application/pdf">
```

Comment: Thank you for response. So tasks in below order
1. Send payload to backend service
2. Backend service will generate pdf and store in S3
3. Display the pdf (from S3 location) with html tags mentioned by you on frontend

Comment: with pleasure ! Backend package exist to handle PDF, check the existing solutions with your backend language

Comment: Yes exactly ! you've got it :)